# Symfony, How to pass a variable to the path?

Tags: javascript, symfony, search, path

I need to pass the var 'busqueda' for the path, if instead of using the var I put text if it works, but to shove the variable tells me there.

JavaScript code in twig.

```
var busqueda = document.getElementById('search_keywords').value;

xmlhttp.open("GET","{{path('searchCorreos', {'page': thisPage, 'search': busqueda } )}}",true); 
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: now I have another problem , I have put that code in a keyup , after making the xmlhttp.send (); not enter more . you know that it can be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a GET request, this should work:

```
var busqueda = document.getElementById('search_keywords').value;

xmlhttp.open("GET","{{ path('searchCorreos', {'page': thisPage}) }}&search=" + busqueda,true); 
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this problem more often (needing to append javascript variables to symfony generated paths/urls) you can make use of the FOSJsRoutingBundle: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle

This allows you to do the following in your javascript source:

```js
var busqueda = document.getElementById('search_keywords').value;
var path = Routing.generate('searchCorreos', { page: 'thisPage', search: busqueda });

xmlhttp.open("GET", path, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```